# Convergence of a Sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

I need to show that the $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\frac{p_{i}(1 - p_{i})}{n^{2}} )$ converges to $0$. Where the $p_{i}$'s are just constants. In particular, they are probabilities from a Bernoulli random sample.

I know the $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \frac{1}{n^{2}} =0$, but I am not sure how to handle the sum.

Comment: $0\leq p_i(1-p_i) \leq \frac{1}{4}$ may help to show convergence. But the limit is not really $0$, unless all $p_i$'s are in $\{0,1\}$: in particular, you seem to be confusing the fact that the series $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges and the fact that its general term $\frac{1}{n^2}$ goes to $0$.

Comment: How did you find this bound on $p_{i}(1-p_{i})$?

Comment: Study the function $f$ defined by $f(x)=x(1-x)$ on $[0,1]$. Its maximum is $\frac{1}{4}$, attained at $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are saying.

Comment: Wait, actually, forget what I said. I assumed there was a typo, the denominator really being $i^2$ and not $n^2$ as you wrote. Was it a mistake, or is it actually $n^2$?

Comment: If it is $n^2$ (and not $i^2$), then $a_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{p_i(1-p_i)}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n p_i(1-p_i)$, and since each summand is bounded as above you get $$0 \leq a_n \leq \frac{1}{n^2}\cdot  n\cdot \frac{1}{4}= \frac{1}{4n}.$$ So by the squeeze theorem the limit is indeed $0$. Now, if the denominator **is** $i^2$ (as I maybe mistakenly assumed), then the limit is not $0$, but some real number between $0$ and $\frac{1}{4}\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{24}$.

Comment: If you want a "cheap" bound on $p_i(1-p_i)$, instead of the best bound $1/4$, you can note that $0\le p_i(1-p_i)\lt 1$. The cheap bound is enough to prove convergence by Comparison.

Comment: @ClementC. No, the denominator is $n^{2}$. I see what you mean now.